# Match parts of lines that begin with specific words

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Given a string that contains multiple domain names, I need to match only the domain names given that the line starts with "`global`". They must be individual matches and not groups.

The Regex is PCRE / .NET 4.7. The same regex would be used in other tools that are PCRE, like BMC software tools.

String content:

```
upstream domain-name some.domain.com some.domain.net 
upstream domain-name another.domain.com 
global domain-name some.domain.com some.domain.net
global domain-name some.domain.local 
downstream domain-name some.domain.com some.domain.net 
downstream domain-name some.domain.com
```

For example, from the lines beginning with `global`, I would like `somedomain.com` `some.domain.net` `some.domain.local` to be returned as 3 separate matches (in a `MatchCollection`)

I know I can use `(?<=global domain-name ).*` but then I'd have to `string.Split()` at the space between `some.domain.com` and `some.domain.net`. It's not an entirely bad solution but I'd really like the matches to be individual.

I am getting closer with `(?<=global domain-name )\S*` but it only returns the first domain name it encounters giving me the output of:

```
somedomain.com
somedomain.local
```

and doesn't match `somedomain.net`.

I've been playing with this for several hours and have been wondering if `\G` might be an option but I don't have a good understanding of that and couldn't get it to work.

I'm sure the solution is pretty easy but I'm not all the comfortable with Regex yet so any pattern help is appreciated!

Comment: No need for regex, simple *string.Split* would work too

Comment: Your regex engine cannot be PCRE and .NET.

Comment: The same regex would be used in other tools that are PCRE, like BMC software tools.

Comment: The same regex is unllkely to work in both PCRE and .NET if it is complicated enough. Why isn't `domain-name` part of your match collection - do you want that skipped?

Comment: You may use [`Regex.Matches(x, @"(?:^global\s+|\G(?!\A)\s+)(\S+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToList()`](https://regex101.com/r/71GXfF/1). If you have a multiline string, you need to replace `\s` with `[\s-[\r\n]]` / `[^\S\r\n]` and compile the regex with `RegexOptions.Multiline` (or just prepend the pattern with `(?m)`)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefix on the `global` lines to include optional domain names, it does it in one expression:

```
var ans = Regex.Matches(src, @"(?<=^global +[\w-.]+ +(?:[\w-.]) +)*)[\w-.]+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

NOTE: This will not work in PCRE which does not support varying length look behind.

Comment: See OP requirement: *The same regex would be used in other tools that are PCRE, like BMC software tools.* You can't rely on LINQ much then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Any sufficiently advanced Regex isn't portable to other systems, but I found one that works in C# anyway. Hey! isn't your comment using LINQ?

Comment: I understand, just it won't work in PCRE, let alone the `\w` shorthand character class. Just FYI, `(?:\w|[-.])+` = `[\w.-]+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be something to match and extract what you want

```
(?m)(?<=^\s*global.*?\s)[\w\.]+\b\.(?:com|net|local)(?=\s|\n|$)
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5Cs*global.*%3F%5Cs%29%5B%5Cw%5C.%5D%2B%5Cb%5C.%28%3F%3Acom%7Cnet%7Clocal%29%28%3F%3D%5Cs%7C%5Cn%7C%24%29&i=upstream%20domain-name%20some.domain.com%20some.domain.net%20%0D%0Aupstream%20domain-name%20another.domain.com%20%0D%0Aglobal%20domain-name%20some.domain.com%20some.domain.net%0D%0Aglobal%20domain-name%20some.domain.local%20%0D%0Adownstream%20domain-name%20some.domain.com%20some.domain.net%20%0D%0Adownstream%20domain-name%20some.domain.com),,, in which `variable-length lookbehind` is applied because `.NET regex` support it.